# Retriving data from existing sqlite database and displaying it into textview (custmoize listview)

Tags: android, listview, android-sqlite

here is my dbhelper.java. the error shows that it could not find the database . can anyone help me see why that it could not find the database table?
database name= crmate
database table = user

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;



import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

public static final String DATABASE_NAME="crmate";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLES="user";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static String path ="/data/data/com.webileapps.navdrawer/databases/";

public static String KEY_ROWID="User_ID";
public static String KEY_USERNAME="User_Name";
public static String KEY_AGE="Age";
public static String KEY_ClINIC="Clinic";
public static String KEY_PHONE="Phone";
public static String KEY_EMAIL="Email";
public static String KEY_DATESIGNUP="Date_Signup";
public static String KEY_CONDITIONID="Condition_ID";
public static String KEY_DOCTORID="Doctor_ID";
public static String KEY_LOGINID="Login_ID";
public static String KEY_ACTIVITYNAME="Activity_Name";
public static String KEY_NOTIFICATIONNAME="Notification_Name";
public static String KEY_GROUPNAME="Group_Name";
public static String KEY_APPROVED="Approved";

private final Context ourContext;
private DbHelper ourhelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase ourdatabase; 
public static Context context;

public DbHelper(Context context){
    //super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.ourContext = context;

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    //check if the database exists
    boolean databaseExist = checkDataBase();

    if(databaseExist){
        // Do Nothing.
    }else{
        this.getWritableDatabase();         
        copyDataBase(); 
    }// end if else dbExist
}

public boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = path + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{ 

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME); 

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = path + DATABASE_NAME; 

    //Open the empty db as the output stream

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName); 
     //transfer bytes from the input file to the output file

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close(); 
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{      
    //Open the database
    String myPath =path + DATABASE_NAME;
    ourdatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  
}


@Override
public synchronized void close() { 
    if(ourdatabase != null)
        ourdatabase.close(); 
    super.close(); 
}

    @Override

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+DATABASE_TABLES);
     //onCreate(db);
}


public String getUserNameFromDB(){
    String query = "select User_First_Name From "+DATABASE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = ourdatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
    String userName = null;
    if(cursor.getCount()>0){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
                userName = cursor.getString(0);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    return userName;
}



public  String [] getDataarray(){

    String[] profilearray = new String[]{ KEY_USERNAME,KEY_AGE,KEY_ClINIC,KEY_PHONE,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_DATESIGNUP
            ,KEY_CONDITIONID,KEY_DOCTORID,KEY_LOGINID,KEY_ACTIVITYNAME,KEY_NOTIFICATIONNAME,KEY_GROUPNAME,KEY_APPROVED
            };

    SQLiteQueryBuilder querybuilder=new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    querybuilder.setTables(DATABASE_TABLES);

  String [] columns= new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_USERNAME,KEY_AGE,KEY_ClINIC,KEY_PHONE,KEY_EMAIL,KEY_DATESIGNUP
            ,KEY_CONDITIONID,KEY_DOCTORID,KEY_LOGINID,KEY_ACTIVITYNAME,KEY_NOTIFICATIONNAME,KEY_GROUPNAME,KEY_APPROVED
            };

    Cursor c= ourdatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLES, columns, null,null, null, null, null);


    if(c.moveToFirst()) {

        int iUserName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);
        int iAge=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGE);
        int iClinic=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ClINIC);
        int iPhone=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHONE);
        int iEmail=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);
        int iDateSignup=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATESIGNUP);
        int iConditionID=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONDITIONID);
        int iDoctorID=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DOCTORID);
        int iLoginID=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOGINID);
        int iActivityName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ACTIVITYNAME);
        int iNotificationName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NOTIFICATIONNAME);
        int iGroupName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_GROUPNAME);
        int iApproved=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_APPROVED);

        profilearray[0] = c.getString(iUserName);
        profilearray[1] = c.getString(iAge);
        profilearray[2] = c.getString(iClinic);
        profilearray[3] = c.getString(iPhone);
        profilearray[4] = c.getString(iEmail);
        profilearray[5] = c.getString(iDateSignup);
        profilearray[6] = c.getString(iConditionID);
        profilearray[7] = c.getString(iDoctorID);
        profilearray[8] = c.getString(iLoginID);
        profilearray[9] = c.getString(iActivityName);
        profilearray[10] = c.getString(iNotificationName);
        profilearray[11] = c.getString(iGroupName);
        profilearray[12] = c.getString(iApproved);
    }


     return profilearray;



}

}
```

this is the page where i display it out .

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user,container,false);
    Resources res=getResources();
    Profile=res.getStringArray(R.array.Profile);

    //condition=res.getStringArray(R.array.Profile_values);
    DbHelper myDbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    try {

            myDbHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        myDbHelper.openDataBase();


        condition=myDbHelper.getDataarray();

        myDbHelper.close();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }


    list=(ListView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    VivzAdapter adapter = new VivzAdapter (getActivity(),Profile);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    return  rootview;

    }




}

public View getView( int position ,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){

    LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(android.content.Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row =inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_list,parent,false);

    TextView myProfile=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.Profile);
    TextView myCondition=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.condition);

    myProfile.setText(ProfileArray[position]);
    myCondition.setText(resultarray[position]);
    return row;
```

Comment: so please post Your Logcat output to see the issue..

Comment: paste your adapter code

Comment: where you are creating `user` table in database ?

Comment: Is database name is same which you copy from assets . Check also extention name of database.

Comment: @ ρяσѕρєя K i created the user table in sqlitebrowser

Comment: @  AmmY yes i copied from assests. there seems to be no extention name of database?

Comment: @AmmY extention name of database is found at where?

Comment: @WongJiaKit like database name is myDb.db or mtDb.sqlite then db and sqlite is extention.

Comment: @AmmY orhh. nope thats no extention for my database . i only name it crmate. should i add a extension?